# Python oct() function missing expected 0oXXXX prefix?

Tags: python, function, octal

Not sure if this is a system or version thing, but I am missing my expected octal prefix when calling the embedded `oct()` function? Here's my example

```
# Base conversion operations
print 'x = 1234 ' ; x = 1234                # all numbers are base10 derivs
print 'bin(x) '   , bin(x)                  # '0b10011010010'
print 'oct(x) '   , oct(x)                  # '02322' -> missing prefix??? expected: 0o02322???
print 'hex(x) '   , hex(x)                  # '0x4d2'

# Using the format() function to suppress prefixes
print 'format(x, \'b\')' , format(x, 'b')   # bin conversion
print 'format(x, \'o\')' , format(x, 'o')   # oct conversion
print 'format(x, \'x\')' , format(x, 'x')   # hex conversion

# version: Python 2.7.13
# output:
# x = 1234
# bin(x)  0b10011010010
# oct(x)  02322               <- unexpected output
# hex(x)  0x4d2
# format(x, 'b') 10011010010
# format(x, 'o') 2322
# format(x, 'x') 4d2
```

I would very well expect a return from `python -c "print oct(1234)"` to be `'0o02322'` or am I missing something obvious?

Walking down the definition for oct from `__builtin__.py__`

```
def oct(number): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
  """
  oct(number) -> string

  Return the octal representation of an integer or long integer.
  """
  return ""
```

returning the octal rep of an int should express a prefixed string?

Comment: Python 2.7 accepts both 0xxxxx, 0oxxxx while Python 3.x accept 0oxxxx only.

Comment: In the old days, octals were shown by a leading zero, only. Thus 0123 meant the octal `0123` == decimal `83`. However, the trend is towards representing octals as `0o123` similar to the hex representation `0x53`. And Python2 is old. :-)

Comment: @falsetru agreed, but im looking at the out not in

Comment: @ehime, As JohanL said, old version of Python 2.x use `0xxx` representation. `oct` should keep backward compatibility. Changing behavior in Python 2.x will confuse who were using it. Python 2.7 accept 0oxxxx representation to help migration to Python 3.x easier.

Comment: @ehime, BTW, I don't understand what `at the out not in` means.

Comment: @falsetru I ment output aka `print` not accepting input as `0oXXX`. Using a prefix as an input appears to convert fine

Comment: @ehime, It's not `print`, but the `oct` who convert.

Comment: How about define your own version of `oct`? `octal = '{:#o}'.format`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144155/discussion-between-ehime-and-falsetru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Python 2.6, only `0XXXXX` octal representation was allowed. In [Python 3.x, only `0oXXXXX` octal representation is allowed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/).

To make it easy to migration from Python 2.x to Python 3.x, Python 2.6 added support for `0oXXXX`. See [PEP 3127: Integer Literal Support and Syntax - What's new in Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3127-integer-literal-support-and-syntax).

```
>>> 0o1234 == 01234  # ran in Python 2.7.13
True
```

Behavior of `oct` in Python 2.x didn't change for backward compatibility.

If you want you can define your own version of `oct`:

```
>>> octal = '{:#o}'.format
>>> octal(10)
'0o12'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look either here: [built-in docs.py/3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#oct) or here: [built-in docs.py/2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#oct)
[image: snapshot from the link-1]